# How to update a particular tag in xml file android

Tags: android

I have certain set of data in different tags inside a xmlfile, I want to change the data of a particular tag periodically, How to get the tag and update it , remaining tags should not get affected by this,

If anybody knows ......pls help...thanks in advance

Comment: More code, more information! What kind of `XML` file do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can change that layout property tag at run time from java class(Activity).

like you want to change the text size of Textview at runtime then you can change :

```
textviewObject.setTextSize(10);
```

Same way you can update other property also.